# Woocommerce HPOS $order->save() method triggers woocommerce_update_order update. so it's not possible to update some other meta inside that hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I found some critical issues and can't find a workaround, maybe somebody did already. For example, I want to update some other order meta e.g. `'order_last_action'`.

```
add_action('woocommerce_update_order', 'order_last_action_callback', 10, 2);
function order_last_action_callback($order_id, $order) {
    $order->update_meta_data( 'order_last_action', date('d-m-y h:i:s') );
    $order->save();
}
```

Which goes in an infinite loop. or if i use `save_post_shop_order` hook it goes to an infinite loop as well. `update_post_meta` not sure can be inside of the callback with HPOS order tables.
Any suggestions on how can I go out with success in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can unhook the action before updating to prevent the loop

```
add_action('woocommerce_update_order', 'order_last_action_callback', 10, 2);
function order_last_action_callback($order_id, $order) {
    remove_action('woocommerce_update_order', 'order_last_action_callback', 10);
    $order->update_meta_data( 'order_last_action', date('d-m-y h:i:s') );
    $order->save();
    add_action('woocommerce_update_order', 'order_last_action_callback', 10, 2);
}
```